# Partition by date in Snowflake procedure removing leading zeros from date

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to partition the data from a Snowflake table and storing it as a parquet file in a S3 bucket. This partition allows me to store the data organised by date (Bucket:///).
I am performing this, using the below Snowflake procedure:

[image]

However, this creates the folders structure in the following way:

[image]

And I wanted it to be: year=2022/month=**0**5/day=**0**1/

To accomplish this I changed month and day variables to:
[image]

However, it produced the same result that I was having before the change.
I even tried to assign some values to both 'day' and 'month' vars like:
var day = '01'
var month = '05'
But it is still removing the leading zeros from the month and day.

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Snowflake SQL to get the correct date format in MM and DD. Here is the SQL

`SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'MM') MON, TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'DD');`

and the stored proc to get the values

```
create or replace procedure date_test()
  returns string
  language javascript
  as
  $$
  var day;
  var mon;
  // Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
  var sql_command = "SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'MM') MON, TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE(), 'DD');"
  // Run the statement.
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
         sqlText: sql_command
         }
      );
  var res = stmt.execute();
    res.next();
  mon = res.getColumnValue(1); 
  day = res.getColumnValue(2);
  return "day:" + day + " month:" + mon;
  $$
  ;

call date_test();
```

output:

| DATE_TEST |
| --- |
| day:13 month:05 |

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add some additional lines of code to prefix the values with zero when required e.g. (pseudo-code)

```
day = if day < 10 then "0"||day else day;
month = if month < 10 then "0"||month else month;
```

Comment: That was what I did with my second screenshot.
However, as I said, it did not worked...
Not even when I set the month and day explicitly with a "0", like: var day = "01".

Comment: If you hardcode the string (in the format you want) in the COPY INTO definition, does it work? If it works, if you hardcode a variable value and use this in the COPY INTO definition? If that works, can you dynamically generate a variable value and use that in the COPY INTO definition and does that work?